# Android TeeChart Line Chart Touch Sensitivity

Tags: android, charts, linechart, teechart

I realized that the Line Chart Drag Point is not really sensitive and it is difficult to select a point to drag. Aside from that, occasionally might trigger the wrong point. I wanted to ask is there workaround can solve this issue? I checked the example code the DragPoint basically selects the entire Line but not the point (I guess?). Other than that, TeeChart is a great library for charts!  Any comments and answers will be highly appreciated.

```
        Line seriesLine;
        seriesLine = new Line(chart.getChart());
        seriesLine.fillSampleValues(5);
        SeriesPointer tmpPointer = seriesLine.getPointer();
        tmpPointer.setInflateMargins(true);
        tmpPointer.setVisible(true);
        tmpPointer.setVertSize(10);
        tmpPointer.setHorizSize(10);
        DragPoint toolDragPoint;
        toolDragPoint = new DragPoint(seriesLine);
        toolDragPoint.setStyle(DragPointStyle.BOTH);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. It seems the pointer isn't clickable&draggable.

I've found the fix for the problem [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=11815) also fixes this. So I've applied the same fix for the Java version.
This will be available with the next maintenance release.